# How to remove ~/Library/Mobile from Apple Music Media Folder Listing?

Tags: macos, itunes, apple-music, music.app

I locally manage my music library with Apple Music app, don't enable Apple Music organizing my library, and do not use the Apple Music streaming service. Recently I upgraded to Mac OS 14.3.1 (and later 14.4) and starting receiving the following error in the Apple Music app on startup:

```
'The file "Application.db" cannot be read. An unknown error occurred'
```

After acknowledging ok, I then receive this message pop up constantly:

```
'The music library file cannot be saved. An unknown error occurred (-54)'
```

However, my music library loads just fine for browsing, but I can't play any music anymore (clicking songs just leads to no actions). My Music Library.musiclibrary folder is still found in its original location, along with the folder of backups -- clicking on any of them doesn't change what's going on.

I was able to find someone with similar symptoms: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/music-app-wrecked-after-update-to-14-3-1.2419347/. That post said they found this site talking about that specific error: https://appleinsider.com/inside/apple-music/tips/how-to-fix-the-apple-music-error--54-on-macos, which led to them rebuilding their library.

I don't want to have to rebuild my entire library to play music again. Taking inspiration from the permissions error, I started poking around the settings for Apple Music and came across this from clicking `Music -> Settings -> Files`:

```
Music Media Folder Location
---------------------------
/Macintosh HD/Users/[me]/Library/Mobile
/path/to/my/library
```

I didn't recognize the first folder, and the second is correct. . When I browsed my Library folder, I found there was **no** Mobile folder whatsoever. I manually created the folder in the terminal, and now I can play music again!

However, I still constantly receive the popup errors, and furthermore, I cannot delete the Library/Mobile folder from the list of locations. If I click "Change", it prompts me to pick a new folder and only changes the **bottom** folder listed, i.e. the correct path to my library. The Library/Mobile folder always stays in the listing.

I suspect this could my ultimate issue given my music started playing again once I created that folder. How can I remove this folder from the listing? Is there a special spot where Apple Music settings are stored and I could edit by hand?

Comment: Small update: going with the permissions idea from the second link above, doing a `chmod 777 ~/Library/Mobile` has made it so the errors have gone away, both on startup and while using the Music app. As far as I can tell though, doing a `ls -al` in that directory is completely empty...

So I'm still left wondering what's going on. Was that folder always there in the Music app and got deleted by the 14.3.1 update and thus causing the errors? Or did it get added by the update to the list without the folder being created? Or something else?

Comment: Another possible solution using privacy settings for the Apple Music application and Music Media folder found here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255486778?sortBy=best